# How can I make some changes on small devices without having to refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to do some changes on the small devices (smaller than 767px) but when I make the window bigger I still have the changes for small devices. Only when I refresh the page I get what I want.

```js
var screenWidth = jQuery(window).width();

function dropdownTeam() {
  if (screenWidth <= 767) {
    jQuery('.nav-team').unbind().click(function() {
      jQuery('.nav-team .container').slideToggle().css('display', 'block');
      jQuery('.text-now').toggleClass('rotate');
    });
  }
}

dropdownTeam();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  window.addEventListener("resize", dropdownTeam, false);
});
```

Comment: The technique is known as 'responsive' and you should use [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for it, not JS

Comment: Jap, I know that..but having click events and slideToggle() it's easier to resolve this with JS. The question is why do i have to refresh the page to see the changes?

Comment: If you know it, why not do it? There's nothing here that can't be done in CSS on that same click handler regardless of screen size, which will avoid your problem. If you did really want to do it in JS then you need to put the original click handler back in when `screenWidth > 767`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this and it works perfectly.
i just moved the var screenWidth in the function.

```
function dropdownTeam(){
    var screenWidth = jQuery(window).width();
    if(screenWidth <= 767){
        jQuery('.nav-team .container').css('display', 'none');

        jQuery('.nav-team').unbind().click(function(){
            jQuery('.nav-team .container').slideToggle().css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('.text-now').toggleClass('rotate');
        });

    }else{
        jQuery('.nav-team .container').css('display', 'block');
    }
}

jQuery(function(){
    dropdownTeam();
});

jQuery(window).resize(function(){
    dropdownTeam();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the comments on the question, I personnaly use media query event handler for multiple situations like adding or removing class regarding to the viewport width without reloading. It's usefull if the user resizes its browser view to move it on a different screen for example, he won't have bad display due to classes which wouldn't have been added or removed because the page changed size without reloading.

So to answer the question, this is the code I use to handle those events:

```
    // media query event handler
      var detectViewPort = function(){
          var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();
       if (viewPortWidth > 767) {
                  // window width is at least 767px
                  $('#wrapper-footer').addClass('fixed-bottom');

 }
     else {
            // window width is less than 768px
          $('#wrapper-footer').removeClass('fixed-bottom');

          }// END media query change
      };

              $(function(){
                detectViewPort();
              });

              $(window).resize(function () {
                 detectViewPort();
              });
```

I let my add/remove class example and you to customise it with your own behaviors.